# no tests defined for extension

Tags: perl, perl-module

I've written an XS wrapper around some C code and am packaging it as a CPAN module, call it "Foo". The original C source is in `src/` and following perlxstut that directory has its own Makefile.PL.

The output of 'make test' now looks like this, and it's that "No tests defined for Foo extension" warning that I'd like to get rid of:

```
All tests successful.
Files=1, Tests=28,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.01 usr  0.00 sys +  0.04 cusr  0.00 csys =  0.05 CPU)
Result: PASS
make[1]: Entering directory `/path/to/Foo/src'
No tests defined for Foo extension.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/path/to/Foo/src'
```

The bits in the created Makefile that are triggering that look like this:

```
subdirs-test ::
    $(NOECHO) $(NOOP)

subdirs-test ::
    $(NOECHO) cd src && $(MAKE) test $(PASTHRU)
```

But I'm unable to find what's creating that second one, or how to make it stop.

What am I missing?

Comment: You're giving yourself this problem by having a second Makefile.PL. Stick to one to both simplify things and avoid this problem.

Comment: *"it's that "No tests defined for Foo extension" warning that I'd like to get rid of"* When a friend pats your shoulder and says, "I think you've had enough. We should go home." you should pay attention to them, not try to get rid of them.

Comment: @ikegami, can you point me at an example or documentation to extra C code from the top-level Makefile.PL?  I'm coming up empty on that.

Comment: @Borodin, haha, yes, all the code is thoroughly tested at the top level. The only thing in there is the third-party C source.

Comment: I find I can set  `OBJECT => ['Foo.o', 'src/thirdparty.o'],` and things are almost right, except that the compiler left `thirdparty.o` in the top-level directory, and the linker is looking for it in `src/thirdparty.o`

Comment: I gave up on eliminating src/Makefile.PL and added "test" to the `SKIP` section. Now I just get "nothing to be done for "test"', which is fine.